# How do I pass a variable value which was collected from user input from one function to another

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a page on htmlin HTML that automatically creates a pie chart with data provided from the user input form. I am trying to pass the values tax, mort, f, transport, and saving from collect() to drawChart() so that it could use those values to create the pie chart, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know why?

```js
function collect() {
  var tax = +document.getElementById("taxes").value;
  document.getElementById('tax').innerHTML = tax;

  var mort = +document.getElementById("mortage").value;
  document.getElementById('mort').innerHTML = mort;

  var f = +document.getElementById("food").value;
  document.getElementById('f').innerHTML = f;

  var transport = +document.getElementById("transportation").value;
  document.getElementById('transport').innerHTML = transport;

  var saving = +document.getElementById("savings").value;
  document.getElementById('saving').innerHTML = saving;

  drawChart(tax, mort, f, transport, saving);
}


function drawChart(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5) {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Expense/Income', '$ per Month'],
    ['Taxes', val1],
    ['Mortage', val2],
    ['Food', val3],
    ['Transportation', val4],
    ['Savings', val5]
  ]);
  var options = {
    'title': 'Monthly Budget',
    'width': 550,
    'height': 400
  };

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<div class="editTable">
  <div class="left">Taxes: </div>
  <div class="right"><input type="number" name="taxes" id="taxes"></div><br><br>
  <div class="left">Mortages: </div>
  <div class="right"><input type="number" name="mortage" id="mortage"></div><br><br>
  <div class="left">Food: </div>
  <div class="right"><input type="number" name="food" id="food"></div><br><br>
  <div class="left">Transportation: </div>
  <div class="right"><input type="number" name="transportation" id="transportation"></div><br><br>
  <button onclick="collect();" class="editRowBtn">Update</button><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide more details as what your error is.

Comment: It just will not work. I am not too sure either if there are any errors but when I open the html page on safari it will not make the pie chart.

Comment: you should understand that your question "doesn't seem to work" too, and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add [a minimal and reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @compscigirl, what's displayed on the console? Have you tried on Chrome? Have you checked what the documentation say about this API? These are all of the details that you can provide to help others answer your question.

Comment: Maybe add console.log statements to every of your variable to see if the result is unusual. For example, console.log(tax); or console.log(typeof tax); if the values is what you wanted, then I would suggest you read the documentation again and see if there is some browser-compadibility issues.